# Accessing Spreadsheet in python using Google API

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

How to access a spreadsheet document in python from Google Sheets using Sheets API ?
I was trying to access a document in my google account. So Will API key be sufficient or should we go with Oauth2client?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the OAuth2 flow. The credentials will be stored in your client_secret.json. This procedure is detailed in the [Python Quickstart Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/python) guide.

[Step 1](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/python#step_1_turn_on_the_api_name): Turn on the Google Sheets API

[Step 2](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/python#step_2_install_the_google_client_library): Install the Google Client Library

[Step 3](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample): Set up the sample

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the library [Gspread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread) for accessing google spreadsheets. You can install gspread using the command

```
pip install gspread
```

or

```
pip install https://github.com/burnash/gspread/archive/master.zip
```

I have written a detailed blog on [how to access google sheets in python using gspread](http://www.indjango.com/access-google-sheets-in-python-using-gspread/). This might help you.